# Access hbs variable in external js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

i am using hbs (express handlebars) to render a page.
i would like to access some variables in chat.hbs  to an external file let us say chat.js(client side)

server side

```
 res.render('chat', {chatroom,user})
```

client side chat.hbs

```
    <div>
      <span id="chatroomid">{{chatroom._id}}</span>
      <span id="userid">{{user._id}}</span>
    </div>
```

I would like to access chatrrom id in an external js file for using socket.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside hbs file

```
      <div hidden>
            <span id="chatroomid" chatroomid ="{{chatroom._id}}"></span>
        </div>
```

i tried this which worked
inside client side js file

```
 const $chatroomid = document.querySelector('#chatroomid')
 const chatroomId = $chatroomid.getAttribute('chatroomid')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to fetch the template `fetch('chat.hbs').then(r => r.text());`, you can share compiled function if that's what you want. Then you need handlebars for client if that express one don't work in browser.

so you code should look like this if used with handlerbars.js:

```
var template = fetch('chat.hbs').then(r => r.text())
      .then(text => Handlebars.compile(text));
```

and then you can render the it with:

```
template.then(fn => {
   var html = fn({chatroom: {_id: 10}, user: {_id: 20}});
   // update DOM with html
});
```